# Nativescript pass parameter to nested component

Tags: android, angular, mobile, nativescript

I'm doing an application with angular 5 and Nativescript. Well, in the app I have different pages (components), and all of them have the same bottom menu that is a single component. My question is how can I pass a parameter to the menu component, because on the menu component I need know witch is the current page, for example for set a class active to the current page item of the menu.

One page example:

```
<Page>
    <ActionBar title="" class="action-bar">
        <StackPanel orientation="horitzontal">
            <Label class="action-title" text="Canciones"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </ActionBar>
    <StackLayout class="page">
    <ListView [items]="filteredSongs" class="songs-listview" (itemTap)="songClick($event)" *ngIf="!isLoading">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label [text]='item.SON_NAME'></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
    <StackLayout verticalAlignment="center" *ngIf="isLoading" class="loading-stack">
        <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ isLoading }}"></ActivityIndicator>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
<main-menu></main-menu> // THE MENU COMPONENT
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your page component is the parent and main-menu is a child. You want use [input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).

1) Change the main-menu tag to something like `<main-menu [currentPage]="Canciones"></main-menu>`. This will send an input to the main-menu component with the name currentPage and the value Canciones.

2) Next you need to change the MainMenuComponent to use the input that we have just bound.

a) add `import { Input } from '@angular/core';`

b) within the component class, declare the Input: `@Input() currentPage: string;`

c) use the currentPage variable as required.

Once you have master the basics of Input Binding, you can change the input type and more generically bind a reference to the current page component.

David